# cc.fovea.plugins.inapppurchase hosted content download

Tags: ios, cordova, in-app-purchase, iap-hosted-content

I use cc.fovea.plugins.inapppurchase, everything works fine except I do not know how to download the hosted content from Apple Server.

In the example I did not find any function for downloading the hosted content.

Is it possible or not ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding this plugin enables a way to communicate with the apple store that retrieves the products, handles payment & restore, and gives you javascript actions that you can use on your app to do whatever you want to do, through javascript instead of objective-c.

Answer (score 0):

It is supported. Please check out the documentation:

https://github.com/Fovea/cordova-plugin-purchase-demo/blob/master/www/js/index.js#L156-L189

The plugin's wiki also contains some more details about it.

https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase/wiki/Apple-Hosted-Content